# Three.js disable depth test

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I use an EffectComposer :

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setDepthTest(false);
...
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer);
```

So I want to disable the depth test but when I do :

```
composer.render();
var gl = renderer.context;
alert(gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_TEST));
```

the value is true and not false. How can I disable the depth test ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this is three years later, but I came across it while researching the z-buffer in Three.js (version r73). In order to disable DEPTH_TEST in the renderer, I ended up doing the following (Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m):

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor(0xaaaaaa);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.context.disable(renderer.context.DEPTH_TEST);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
var gl = renderer.context;
alert(gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_TEST));
```

with the key being`renderer.context.disable(renderer.context.DEPTH_TEST)` when creating the renderer.

I attempted to use `renderer.setDepthTest(false)` at first but it actually did not load. I didn't delve in depth to see if this is just an interaction with my existing project, an actual bug, or possibly removed, but for now I recommend just using the above working method.

Comment: `renderer.setDepthTest(false)` will not work; instead, use `gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST)` which will disable depth tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
```

Comment: I tried but it seems that gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST) or gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST) is called in composer.render()